Add drop-down to change status using action in Nova laravel
I am using Nova laravel dashboard. I want to achieve is to add drop-down with option and by that I can change status in database. I added action for changing status, now I want a way to add drop-down in action box so admin can select the option and when confirm the can will be made to database. Is there a way to do so? Or is there any other way to achieve the desired output.
Help would be really appreciated!!!

class Status extends Action
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;

    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
       foreach($models as $model) {
          $model->update([
             'status' => $fields->status
          ]);
       }
       return Action::message('Status has been successfully updated!');
    }

    public function fields()
    {
       return [
          Select::make('Status')->options([
             'approved' => 'Approve',
             'declined' => 'Decline',
          ])->default(function ($request) {
              return 'approved';
          })
       ];
    }
}

you can pass your selected drop-down option status code on click button and perform action as above
